# How to create a function to test normality of each variable

Tags: python, function, loops, scipy.stats

I am trying to build a function that iteratively returns i) JarqueBera test stat, ii) JarqueBera pvalue, iii) the slope, intercept and determination coeff of the probplot, and iv) the probplot itself. All is intended to be returned for a single variable at a time.

```
def normality(c):
    JB_test_stat = ss.jarque_bera(c)[0]
    JB_pval = ss.jarque_bera(c)[1]
    probplot_slope = ss.probplot(c, plot = plt)[1][0]
    probplot_interc = ss.probplot(c, plot = plt)[1][1]
    probplot_r = ss.probplot(c, plot = plt)[1][2]
    return(print("Skewness:",c.skew(),"\nExcess kurtosis:",c.kurt(),"\nJarque-Bera stat:",JB_test_stat," pvalue:", JB_pval,"\nSlope:",probplot_slope,"Intercept:",probplot_interc, "r:",probplot_r,"\n"))
```

Unfortunately, when I call the function on my dataframe[numeric_cols], being numeric_cols a list,

```
for c in numeric_cols:    
    normality(df[c])
```

I get all the numeric results in the return statement correctly, but at the bottom a single probplot with all variables plotted in a messy way, whereas what I expect is to get the numerical results for each variable along with its corresponding probplot.

Skewness: 0.1004187952160102
Excess kurtosis: -0.543819517693596
Jarque-Bera stat: 7.593972235734294  pvalue: 0.022438296430201454
Slope: 4.3135147782152465 Intercept: 25.5 r: 0.9947611456706487

Skewness: -0.1560130144763728
Excess kurtosis: -1.2824901951466612
Jarque-Bera stat: 38.56183464454786  pvalue: 4.23061985443951e-09
Slope: 11.492550446207257 Intercept: 19.535714285714285 r: 0.9668502992894236

Skewness: 0.2347601433103727
Excess kurtosis: -1.242639192300385
Jarque-Bera stat: 39.0662449724179  pvalue: 3.287552452491127e-09
Slope: 11.545683807955731 Intercept: 15.714285714285714 r: 0.9647448407831439

Skewness: 0.24353437856100904
Excess kurtosis: -1.1969521906230485
Jarque-Bera stat: 36.98912338336009  pvalue: 9.287822622106034e-09
Slope: 1013.985374629207 Intercept: 1411.4436090225563 r: 0.9682492605786011

Skewness: 2.837876986150242
Excess kurtosis: 9.516628330654008
Jarque-Bera stat: 2675.4455000782764  pvalue: 0.0
Slope: 2.6057664781688454 Intercept: 1.8533834586466167 r: 0.7776054895177505

Skewness: 2.406153102778617
Excess kurtosis: 7.002529753885085
Jarque-Bera stat: 1573.6596724989513  pvalue: 0.0
Slope: 1.714847443415902 Intercept: 1.287593984962406 r: 0.8152919114915671

Skewness: 0.9337529310147361
Excess kurtosis: 0.45862734243889847
Jarque-Bera stat: 81.22389376608798  pvalue: 0.0
Slope: 605.3354149443196 Intercept: 717.75 r: 0.9550404156079808

Skewness: -3.030640857636996
Excess kurtosis: 15.686541621050898
Jarque-Bera stat: 6154.761075129672  pvalue: 0.0
Slope: 11.37955609488042 Intercept: 77.82387218045113 r: 0.8711740556551902

Skewness: 6.398317104228115
Excess kurtosis: 49.10097819497357
Jarque-Bera stat: 56029.69126113364  pvalue: 0.0
Slope: 0.41431397013222515 Intercept: 0.1917293233082707 r: 0.48503363895959983

Skewness: 6.204252341215679
Excess kurtosis: 47.28662289867727
Jarque-Bera stat: 52010.755388690835  pvalue: 0.0
Slope: 0.4947086253584861 Intercept: 0.23496240601503762 r: 0.5050004904368586

Skewness: 2.06633193738682
Excess kurtosis: 5.770784034742405
Jarque-Bera stat: 1098.0175308306793  pvalue: 0.0
Slope: 0.12821997057404685 Intercept: 0.11328947368421052 r: 0.8619773533976459

Skewness: 2.9189857433086495
Excess kurtosis: 16.837230233306762
Jarque-Bera stat: 6909.724155123523  pvalue: 0.0
Slope: 0.07805612907589729 Intercept: 0.07265037593984962 r: 0.8632361803763113

Skewness: 1.2633082232077495
Excess kurtosis: 1.5265390704578943
Jarque-Bera stat: 190.6495836394772  pvalue: 0.0
Slope: 2.09821120102269 Intercept: 2.1146616541353382 r: 0.9211028014650718

Skewness: 3.091346622737553
Excess kurtosis: 8.530683362863476
Jarque-Bera stat: 2421.371001114453  pvalue: 0.0
Slope: 0.16657862407594715 Intercept: 0.09022556390977444 r: 0.5658043763386988

[image]

How could fix it?
Thank you all in advance

Comment: Why would you return a `print` statement?? Also, please add your expected output and an example of the current output.

Comment: What about now man? I still don't know pretty much how to use the posting interface

Comment: You mean you want a separate figure for each? Or something else? The question is still not very clear.

Comment: Exactly, one probplot figure for each variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `plt.figure()` in your function, so that every call to the function opens a new figure.
On a completely different note, using `return(print('stuff'))` is superfluous. If you really want to print the results then just use `print` with no `return`.
It would be more pythonic and generally better practice to return the values you're currently printing, and then print them externally:

```
def normality(c):
    JB_test_stat = ss.jarque_bera(c)[0]
    JB_pval = ss.jarque_bera(c)[1]
    probplot_slope = ss.probplot(c, plot = plt)[1][0]
    probplot_interc = ss.probplot(c, plot = plt)[1][1]
    probplot_r = ss.probplot(c, plot = plt)[1][2]
    return c.skew(), c.kurt(), JB_test_stat, JB_pval, probplot_slope, probplot_interc, probplot_r


for c in numeric_cols:    
    c.skew(), c.kurt(), JB_test_stat, JB_pval, probplot_slope, probplot_interc, probplot_r = normality(df[c])
    print("Skewness:",c.skew(),
          "\nExcess kurtosis:",c.kurt(),
          "\nJarque-Bera stat:",JB_test_stat,
          " pvalue:", B_pval,
          "\nSlope:",probplot_slope,
          "Intercept:",probplot_interc, 
          "r:",probplot_r,"\n")
```